# Scp Command issue

Tags: ssh, scp

I am trying to copy the image maldives.jpg from another computer into mine using scp. However when I enter the line:

```
scp -r ubuntucomp@192.168.1.14: ~/maldives.jpg
```

I get:

```
1bf7392fd8b1bdab035e1e4c0000000f-0                                                                             100%  463     0.5KB/s   00:00    
.xsession-errors                                                                                               100%   11KB  10.8KB/s   00:00    
urlclassifierkey3.txt                                                                                          100%  154     0.2KB/s   00:00    
content-prefs.sqlite                                                                                           100%  224KB 224.0KB/s   00:00    
sessionstore.js                                                                                                100% 1047KB   1.0MB/s   00:00    
bookmarks-2017-03-16.json                                                                                      100% 5231     5.1KB/s   00:00    
.parentlock                                                                                                    100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00    
search.sqlite                                                                                                  100%   64KB  64.0KB/s   00:00    
permissions.sqlite                                                                                             100%  128KB 128.0KB/s   00:00    
sessionCheckpoints.json                                                                                        100%  288     0.3KB/s   00:00    
localstore.rdf                                                                                                 100%  852     0.8KB/s   00:00    
compatibility.ini                                                                                              100%  177     0.2KB/s   00:00    
sessionstore.bak                                                                                               100% 3709     3.6KB/s   00:00    
mimeTypes.rdf                                                                                                  100% 4485     4.4KB/s   00:00    
xulstore.json                                                                                                  100%  265     0.3KB/s   00:00    
1490021508228.927ef3ee-da96-4dd9-a5e8-3f1f0f1cb899.main.jsonlz4                                                100% 4715     4.6KB/s   00:00    
state.json                                                                                                     100%   51     0.1KB/s   00:00
```

I was expecting this command to copy the image into home. I don't understand what its copying, since I don't see this in the computer's home folder.

Comment: remove the space between `:` and `~` and try again. Also you don't need to use `-r` which is for dealing with files and directories recursively. Just run `scp ubuntucomp@192.168.1.14:~/maldives.jpg` and share the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `scp` like this

```
scp <source> <target>
```

in your case it would be something along the lines of:

```
scp ubuntucomp@192.168.1.14:~/maldives.jpg .
```

where `ubuntucomp@192.168.1.14:~/maldives.jpg` is the source and `.` the target - the directory you run scp in.

Answer (score 1):

It is copying all files and directories from the remote default directory.

You did not enter the path to the file you want to copy.

The `-r` key is "recursively copy entire directories".

So the correct command will be something like this:

```
scp ubuntucomp@192.168.1.14:~/maldives.jpg ~
```

I am assuming that the path of `maldives.jpg` on the remote computer is `~/maldives.jpg`.

Comment: when I try that I get the message: scp: .: not a regular file

Comment: Where your `maldives.jpg` is stored on the remote?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you put `-r` flag, which considered as **Recursively copy entire directories** (from `man scp`). So it will copy entire directory on given path, and also the subpath on the given path.

The command you want is:

```
scp ubuntucomp@192.168.1.14: ~/maldives.jpg .
```

Where **dot** (.) is the current active folder on terminal, so copy from server and paste here.

You can also change **dot** (.), to any destination directory you want to paste the file.